# popen not forwarding args correctly - Python

Tags: python, linux

I am using Raspbian and attempting to run a very simple cmd using python with the **popen** function.
I am very new to *linux* and *python*

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
po = Popen(['airmon-ng', 'start wlan0 10'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
out
```

returns

```
'\n\nusage: airmon-ng <start|stop|check> <interface> [channel or frequency]\n\n'
```

The error msg returned can be created outside of the popen function when running only **airmon-ng** without parameters, which makes me believe that **popen** is not forwarding the *args* correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate comamnd line arguments correctly; `start`, `wlan0`, `10` should be separated command line arguments:

```
proc = Popen(['airmon-ng', 'start', 'wlan0', '10'],
             stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out)
```

---

The way in the question is like invoking the command as follow in the shell:

```
airmon-ng 'start wlan0 10'
```

which is different from:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0 10
```

Comment: note that the whole point of passing a list of parameters is that you've already split them up  :)

Comment: @Eevee, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: directed at the asker — when you use the shell, it just sees the single string `"airmon-ng start wlan0 10"` and now needs to split it on whitespace etc.  using a list (a data structure) ought to mean you've already done that work.